# How to set background image for div between top and bottom of pages?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap webpage with header and footer and I would like to set a background image for the div in between.
My goal is that the background image could cover all area between header and footer (div id=xx in code below) while I don't need to hard coded height and width, but failed.

Can you please help?

```
<body>
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <center>
    <div id="xx" style="background:url(images/background.jpg) no-repeat;background-size:940px 500px;height:500px;width:940px" title="KnowSG" align="left" id="hplogo">
      <h3>"From beginning of 2016, it is mandatory that employers must issue payslip to employees."</h3>
      <h3 style="color:red">"Penalty is SGD 1000 for first month and SGD 2000 for subsequent months."</h3>
    </div>
  </center>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="push"></div>
 </div>
 <footer class="footer">
   <div class="container">
     <center>
     </center>
   </div>
 </footer>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  /* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
}

/* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */
#wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  /* Negative indent footer by it's height */
  margin: 0 auto -50px;
}
#push {height: 50px;}

.footer {
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.footer > .container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I cleaned your code up a bit. You had 2 `id` attributes on the same element which you shouldn't do. and I added a class.

```
 <div id="wrap">
   <div class="container">
     <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
       <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="navbar-header">
           <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </nav>
   <div class="container-fluid">
   <center>
     <div id="xx" title="KnowSG" align="left">
       <h3>"From beginning of 2016, it is mandatory that employers must issue payslip to employees."</h3>
       <h3 style="color:red">"Penalty is SGD 1000 for first month and SGD 2000 for subsequent months."</h3>
     </div>
   </center>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="push"></div>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <center>
      </center>
    </div>
  </footer>
```

```
#xx {
 background-image: url('http://placehold.it/1920x1080.gif');
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for comment and fixed my error, but still I cannot see the background image. Any more suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your background image is either not where you think it is, or missing? Quick test: in a new browser window: `http://yourdomain.com/images/background.jpg` *(using the file / dir names from your question code)*

***This might be the problem:*** Note also that **if** you have an external stylesheet *(in your example you styled the `#xx` div using inline html attribute)*, **and if** that stylesheet is in a subfolder, such as `/css`, you must do this (because the images folder is not directly underneath the css folder):

```
background:url(../images/background.jpg) no-repeat; /* Note the ../ prefix */
```

I created a jsFiddle and substituted the placeholder website `placekittens.com` for your hard-coded image - it works fine.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/txLc3d8z/)

Observations:

If you want the background image flush up against the header and footer, you must make these adjustments (as I did at top of the jsFiddle's CSS):

```
.container-fluid h3 {margin:0;}
.navbar {margin:0;}
```

You can do *this* if you want the bg image flush up against the header, but not the text:

```
.container-fluid h3 {margin:0;padding:50px;}
```